# What type of object/property is a prototype getter and setter?

Tags: javascript

Reading [John Resig's article about Javascript getters and setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) I see a structure I'm unfamiliar with in Javascript:

```
Field.prototype = {
    get value(){
        return this._value;
    },
    set value(val){
        this._value = val;
    }
};
```

Prototype is an object like many others but the get and set portions here seem unfamiliar. By what name are they referred? They don't look like typical properties of an object (following the `"key":"value"` syntax) and they don't quite look like standard functions either.

Is this simply syntactic sugar that the JS engine converts into something more recognisable?

**Update:**

The real crux of my question is: Since `{ foo(){} }` isn't valid syntax, what makes it valid given a `get` or `set` operator? `{ get foo(){} }`

Comment: `get` and `set` are both listed on MDN under the *operators* documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get. They also refer to them as getters and setters. I guess they are similar to the `delete`/`typeof`/`yield` operators.

Comment: Ah, the day I learned about it I felt somehow dirtier. These should never have existed, IMO.

Comment: Thanks @RGraham. I just found some info on the get operator on MDN. The next part is really how it fits in with the object literal notation. Are they treated as special cases or is that syntax actually valid as standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me a little bit of reading to work out exactly how this might be used, so whilst @RGraham has pointed to a good bit of documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get), I thought I'd provide a usage example.

Basically, **the "get" and "set" operators allow you to override the behaviour that you would get when accessing the member variables directly.**

This means you can, for example:

- Present a member variable with one name publicly, and then store it with another name privately.
- Perform an operation on the value before storing it.
- Present something that appears to be member variable whilst it is, in fact, a function.

All the above can (of course) be done by defining functions on the object, with the difference being that the functions would have to be called as such.

With this notation, the functions are called even though the notation appears to be referencing a member variable.

I personally don't like it - I imagine it can lead to some very confusing code, particularly when debugging.  But it's there to be used if you want to...

Example

```
var Field = {
    get value(){
        return this._value;
    },
    set value(val){
        this._value = val + 1;
    }
};

Field.value = 100

console.log( Field.value );
```

Will output:

```
101
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zV8Kf/1/

On to the particular "Why is `{ get foo(){} }` valid?" question:

I read this as:

- Create an object
- Define a function that does nothing
- Assign the function so that this is the getter for 'foo'

This means that references to foo against this object will return `undefined`

You can see the behaviour here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VHAhA/

If you think of `get` as being approximate to `foo: function` (I know it's not quite, but it does state "I am going to define a function - assign it to this", then it is syntactically similar to:

```
{ foo: function foo() {} }
```

It can't be compared to `{ foo(){} }`, as in this example you don't tell JavaScript that you are about to define something, nor where to put it once you do.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I'm actually ok with the purpose and usage of the syntax. I get how it works and what it can be used for so my question is still really about this difference in syntax compared to other objects. Since `{ foo(){} }` isn't valid, why is it valid with the `get` operator?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean.  Can you update the original question with fuller examples of "this is invalid" - "this is valid" - "why?"

Comment: Thanks for adding that last bit Rob. Is that what the JS engine actually does? Does it expand this out into the full form you've provided or is something else happening?

Comment: No idea!   Sorry, that's beyond my knowledge.  Having said that - I seriously doubt it, as its behaviour is significantly different.  The getter and setter definitions *override* the behaviour of `foo.bar`, rather than simply define the behaviour of `foo.bar()`.  If you console.log the object in the first example you see that `get value` and `set value` are defined as distinct entities in the object.

Comment: I'm grateful for the time you've spent answering, Rob. I think I'm a touch closer to understanding.